# Bifurcation diagram using python

Tags: matplotlib

I have a simple question. Can we create Bifurcation diagram from any type of equation or just from the equation of logistic map like

```
x=r (1-x)
```

What is the main idea of making a bifurcation diagram. I am working on this for last couple of weeks but got no idea. I just see the same equation plotting everywhere like I mentioned above. I do have different equation like

```
x[i+1]= a*x[i]*2**n+b (mod2**n)/2**n
```

where `mod2**n` indicates the remainder after division by `2**n`.

I have to write a code to make a bifurcation diagram for above equation.
I tried to change `a` but it does not work.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
def iter_map(a,N): 
    x=np.zeros(N) 
    x[0]=0.5 
    for i in range(N-1): 
        d=(a*x[i]*(2**n) +b)%(2**n) 
        x[i+1]=d/2**n 
    return x 
N=5 
n=8 
a0 = 1.0 
a_max= 4 
step= 0.001 
plt.figure()
for b in [0,1]: 
    for a in np.arange(a0, a_max, step): 
        x = iter_map(a, 8) 
        plt.plot(a*np.ones_like(x),x) 
plt.xlabel(r'$a$') 
plt.ylabel(r'$x$') 
plt.show()
```

The result does not look as expected

[image]

Comment: Equation goes like this x[i+1]=a*x[i]*2**n +b (mod 2**n) /2**n.  where mod2n indicates the remainder after division by 2**n.

Comment: Please share your code that does not seem to work. Questions with code have a higher chance to be answered.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def iter_map(a,N):
    x=np.zeros(N)
    x[0]=0.5
    for i in range(N-1):
        d=(a*x[i]*2**n +b)%2**n
        x[i+1]=d/2**n
    return x

N=5
n=8


a0 = 1.0
a_max= 4
step= 0.001
plt.figure()
for b in [0,1]:
    for a in np.arange(a0, a_max, step):
        x = iter_map(a, 8)
        plt.plot(a*np.ones_like(x),x)

plt.xlabel(r'$\a$')
plt.ylabel(r'$x$')
plt.show()

Comment: I am new here and have no idea how to post a comment exactly like in a coding format.

Comment: Updated the question with the code from the comments above. Fixed a few typos in the process.

Comment: Why do you think that this equation would have a bifurcation? Bifurcation is an indicator of a transition from regular to chaotic behavior. In what combination of parameters do you expect to see such a transition?